# Hibernate exception isnt getting caught

Tags: java, exception

I facing problem where every try catch block is somehow ignored.

I have structure like this:

```
void A(){
   // some logic
   try{
       service.createItem(...);
   }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("blabla...");
   }
}

service$createItem(...){
   // some logic - building item.
   try{
      dao.saveItem( item );
   }catch(Exception e){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("bla bla");
   }
}

dao$saveItem(Item item){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(item);
}
```

Item is unique, howeven when i try to insert duplicate, instead of catching exception and printing "bla bla", it just prints whole stacktrace -- like exception isnt handled at all.

Debugging shows it doesnt even jump into catch block of `A` method, i havent met with anything like this before, have anyone had this situation?

What could cause the problem?

Thanks!

stackStrace:

> used by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could
>   not execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3167)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3682)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:609)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]     ... 35 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '2-1' for key 'PRIMARY'   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_121]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_121]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_121]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_121]    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3167)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3682)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:609)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]     ... 35 more
>
> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '2-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: show the stack trace and some more code might be useful `// some logic - building item`

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: Can you try using try catch on session.save(item)?

Comment: tried it... same result

Comment: I am pretty sure we miss something because you are not sharing whole code.
Can you show more please? Everything matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason you can't catch it this way is that Exception appear during Transaction flush and not during try-catch or save block.

Maybe think about checking if the record exist in the database before trying to save it again?

So to solve the problem you must make try-catch on Class/method that is Transactional or move Transactional to Class that save to database.

Comment: what is the way how to catch exception during flush?

Comment: @Darlyn you can always try to try-catch in higher level class (class that handless Transaction or A() )

Comment: Is the exception you shared full exception code or just a part? Because I think there is more.

Comment: @Transactional annotation is on A method, log is full -- but i have been messing with logger so i might have omitted something, im going to check into it

Comment: Hm, i have put @Transactional on service$createItem(..) method - which is logically more correct but practically should be the same and it solved the problem

Comment: Happy to hear that it works now. 
If my answer solved your problem then please mark it as solution.
If not then please mark your answer as a solution so question can be closed.